# Z-index not working all the time on hover menu

Tags: css

When hovering over 'Find a Hotel' in the menu in the middle of the page a hover menu appears using css only, no javascript.

http://dusit.syndacast.com/dusitthani/meetings/

however on the home page the hover menu is below other elements even though the z-index is 99999

http://dusit.syndacast.com/dusitthani/

Both pages are using almost identical templates but I cannot see what the difference would be?

Thank you

Comment: If you use so huge `z-index` is probably because you don't understand it correctly. I suggest reading [What No One Told You About Z-Index](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

Answer (score 3):

Adding `z-index:0` to `.relative-item` and `z-index:1` to `.blueBar.brand` should fix it.

```
 .relative-item {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 0;
 }

.blueBar.brand{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `z-index` in the parent element instead.

Add or update your css to this:

```
/* currently this element has position:relative; set */
.cover-photo-div {
  z-index: 1;
}

.blueBar.brand {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will fix the issue.

```
.cover-photo-div {
  z-index: 1;
}
.blueBar {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```